# How to open Windows command prompt from bat file pre-configured?

Tags: batch-file, command-line

For my command prompt window on XP I have configured its window size, font, other settings. So when I open it from the Start menu it is opened pre-configured with my settings.

But when I open cmd from a `.bat` file it is opened with defaults settings - small window, default font, default mouse settings:

```
# My .bat file with some code...
start cmd.exe   <-- this call opens the default command prompt window
```

Is it possible to open it from `.bat` file pre-configured?

Comment: what if you open a shortcut to bat file?In the shortcut you can define colors , font and etc.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean. I run this bat file from command line, its folder is in my PATH. It starts two servers and after that opens a new command prompt that a want to be configured already. What is the shortcut I need to customize?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I have a vague memory when you customize a command prompt it creates a .pif file.  If it exists you have to launch that.